# Android ADK USB library not loading

Tags: android, usb, accessory, adk

Just started trying out the Android ADK, but I can't get the DemoKit project to install on my development phone, which is a Droid X running Android 2.3.3.

When I try to run the DemoKit project using the phone as the device, I get this from the console:

```
[2011-06-09 17:03:54 - DemoKitLaunch] Installing DemoKitLaunch.apk...
[2011-06-09 17:03:56 - DemoKitLaunch] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

And further inspection of the LogCat shows that it's an issue with the com.android.future.usb.accessory library:

```
06-09 17:08:38.124: ERROR/PackageManager(1320): Package com.google.android.DemoKit requires unavailable shared library com.android.future.usb.accessory; failing!
```

I've tried changing the build target around- from Google API 2.3.3 to 3.1, but that doesn't fix it. Google API 3.1 has the com.android.future.usb.accessory library in the .jar file, whereas the 2.3.3 API does not. It fails with both.

When I run it in the emulator, it installs and launches the DemoKit app just fine, but nothing I try makes it install and run on an actual phone.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html: it requires 2.3.4, not 2.3.3.

Comment: Followed this to the letter. I see a lot of people having this missing library problem with the Google Maps api, but that's fixed by switching the target to Google API instead of Android. My target was already set correctly.

Comment: It says this about the build target: "For Build Target, select Google APIs (Platform 2.3.3, API Level 10).", which I have. I can't see a Google API 2.3.4 package in the SDK Manager.

Comment: Ah. I think if you set your target to 11 but your minimum to 10 in the AndroidManifest.xml you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Droid X is running Android 2.3.3, it does not support Accessory Mode, which was added to the Android platform in 2.3.4.  You will not be able to use the ADK with your Droid X; you'll have to stick with the emulator.  Sorry.

I just had the same problem with my Android 2.3.3 device (a Coby Kyros MID7015 which I upgraded from Android 2.1 to Android 2.3.3).